# Block list is lost when copying a block blob i Azure Storage and AzCopy

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I'm copying a Block Blob from our production environment to our test environment using the copy function in Azure Storage Explorer (context menu Copy / Paste).
I have also tested this by using command line AzCopy, which looks to me as the same as copying in Azure Storage Explorer.

I have verified that the source Block Blob has a blocklist (using Python SDK) and the destination (copied) Block Blob has an empty block list.

Is there a way (parameters etc) to keep the block list when copying Block Blobs except for downloading the blob and post it as a new Blob?
I could create a program that could do this but it seems weird to not have this built-in in the Azure Storage Explorer or AzCopy.

Thanks

Comment: Interesting question. Never really thought about it. Just curious, why do you need this information to be copied over?

Comment: We are copying from production environment to test environment to be able to manipulate the blobs without fear of damaging production blobs. If there is another way to do this I would more than happy to learn that :)

Comment: Once you copy the blob, a new blob is created that has no link to the original blob. You should be able to make any changes that you would like to the copied blob without impacting the source blob.

Comment: Yes, that is true. However, I would like to extract data from one particular block in the blob, alter the block data or adding more data to the block. Without the block list it seems to be hard to insert and/or alter data in specific position in the blob without downloading all the data and recreate the blob. Without a block list I'm afraid performance will suffer. Also, if we are to use this as a backup solution (AzCopy or Azure's own), the block list will be gone. If you can think of any workarounds I would be glad to learn.